Prove $\|u\|_{C^{2,\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^3)}\leq C\|f\|_{C^{0,\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^3)}$ for $u(x)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{f(y)}{|x - y|}dy$

Assume $ 0 < \alpha < 1 $, and the function $ f \in C^{0, \alpha}(\mathbb{R}^3) $ has compact support. Define the function
$$
u(x) = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{f(y)}{|x - y|} \, dy.
$$
Prove that there exists a constant $ C $ depending only on $ \alpha $ such that
$$
\|u\|_{C^{2,\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^3)} \leq C \|f\|_{C^{0,\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^3)}.
$$

According to the hint of this problem, I should consider that $$
\frac{\partial^2 u(x)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{|x-y|\geq \epsilon} \left( \frac{3(x_i - y_i)(x_j - y_j)}{|x-y|^5} - \frac{\delta_{ij}}{|x-y|^3} \right) f(y) \, dy.
$$
where $ \delta_{ij} $ is the Kronecker delta function. Then I have
$$
\Delta u(x) = (\partial_{x_1}\partial_{x_1} + \partial_{x_2}\partial_{x_2} + \partial_{x_3}\partial_{x_3}) u(x) = f(x).
$$
I believe this idea is feasible.
But actually, I only know the "formal derivative" is $$
\frac{\partial^2 u(x)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} =  \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{\mathbb R^3} \left( \frac{3(x_i - y_i)(x_j - y_j)}{|x-y|^5} - \frac{\delta_{ij}}{|x-y|^3} \right) f(y) \, dy
$$
How can I deal with the singularity? (on other words, why can I assume that it equals to its principle value?) And then how can I finish the proof? Any help is OK.
Now I can only get $\|u\|_{L^\infty}\le C\|f\|_{L^\infty}\le C \|f\|_{C^{0,\alpha}}$.
UPDATE:
I can get $\|u\|_{L^\infty}\le C\|f\|_{L^\infty}$ by the property of compact support. And I saw this lemma from Chapter 4 of Gilbarg-Trudinger, can I use this to solve this problem?

Lemma 4.4. Let $B_1=B_R\left(x_0\right), B_2=B_{2 R}\left(x_0\right)$ be concentric balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $f \in C^\alpha\left(\bar{B}_2\right), 0<\alpha<1$, and let $w$ be the Newtonian potential of $f$ in $B_2$. Then $w \in$ $C^{2, a}\left(\bar{B}_1\right)$ and
$$
\left|D^2 w\right|_{0, \alpha, B_1}^{\prime} \leqslant C|f|_{0, \alpha, B_2}^{\prime},
$$
i.e.,
$$
\left|D^2 w\right|_{0 ; B_1}+R^\alpha\left[D^2 w\right]_{\alpha{;} B_1} \leqslant C\left(|f|_{0 ; B_2}+R^\alpha[f]_{\alpha; B_2}\right)
$$
where $C=C(n, \alpha)$.


UPDATE AGAIN
I've found a useful method but it looks so complicated:
Step 1: Consider $\|u\|_{L^{\infty}}\le C\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}$
Step 2: When $|x|\to\infty$ we have $|D_{ij}u|\to0$, so take $M$ such that $\sup_{|x|<\frac M2}|D_{ij}u|=\|D_{ij}u\|_{L^{\infty}}$, then we can use $\sup_{|x|<\frac M2}|D_{ij}u|\le C\left(\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}+M^\alpha\|f\|_{\alpha}\right) $
Step 3: Use $\|u\|_{\alpha}\le C\|f\|_{\alpha} $
Step 4: Consider $\sup|Du|\le \sqrt{2\cdot\sup|D^{2}u|\cdot\sup|u|}$ to finish it
Is there any simple way to solve it?

This is the famous Schauder regularity estimate for elliptic equations (you can reformulate the problem in to a boundary value problem). The catch is that $f\in C^0$ is not enough for $u$ to gain 2 in the exponent for differentiability, i.e., $u$ may not be $C^2$. The technique involved is featured in Gilbarg-Trudinger 6.1. Do you actually need to show the estimate using the hint given?

@ShuhaoCao , I find that in Gilbarg-Trudinger 6.2, in Theorem 6.6, where only need $f\in C^{\alpha}$. And this exercise is from Shiwu Yang's lecture note. He divided this problem into 3 parts: first, show $u\in C^2(\mathbb R^3)$ and $$\frac{\partial^2u(x)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{|x-y|\geq\epsilon}\left( \frac{3(x_i-y_i)(x_j-y_j)}{|x-y|^5}-\frac{\delta_{ij}}{|x-y|^3}\right)f(y) dy.$$Secondly, prove that $$\Delta u(x)=(\partial_{x_1}\partial_{x_1}+\partial_{x_2}\partial_{x_2}+\partial_{x_3}\partial_{x_3})u(x) = f(x).$$And the question above is 3rd part.

@ShuhaoCao, do you mean this question is lack of some condition? But ... actually, it let me prove $u\in C^2$ at first. Is there anything wrong?

Nothing wrong. What I meant to say is that the gist of this problem is to learn how to exploit the extra $\alpha$ differentiability. BTW: in Gilbarg-Trudinger, $C^{\alpha}$ is $C^{0,\alpha}$.

@ShuhaoCao, I looked through the proof of that theorem, but the proof was not along this line of thought. I would like to know how to complete the proof under this hint.

@ShuhaoCao, I've updated this question. Could you give me some ideas or hints to solve it? It seems that I cannot imitate the case of bounded area to solve this one.

Aside from @Gio67 's answer, in order to exploit G-T's Newtonian potential differentiation formula and Lemma 4.4, you just need to choose the smaller ball to contain the support of $f$.

You can find the proof for the computation of the second derivatives in my lecture notes harmonic-analysis on page 47. It's a long proof, but all the details are there. The only change is formula (76), where instead, you use the Holder continuity to compute
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le|f|_{C^{0,\alpha}}|x-y|^\alpha.$$
In turn,
$$\left|\frac{\partial^2\Gamma}{\partial x_j\partial x_i}(x-y)(f(x)-f(y)\right|\le \frac{C|f|_{C^{0,\alpha}}}{|x-y|^{N-\alpha}},$$ which is still integrable in $B(x,1)$.
The other change is that the term $II_2$ is well-defined because $f$ has compact support.
To prove the Holder estimates, you need to adapt formula (4.11) in Lemma 4.4 in Gilbarg and Trudinger.
